# Find an unused number in a bunch of numbers

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a huge table filled with numbers (1001001..1009999) and there are certainly a bunch of unused numbers in that area. So, I could have all these numbers returned by doing:

```
SELECT MY_IDENTIFIER FROM MY_TABLE
```

that would return all used numbers. How could I get a list of unused numbers from that table? I work serverside (rhino/jaxer) with JavaScript and my database is Oracle 10g.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need some sort of a report, or do you need to use them programmatically?

Comment: To expand on @Eric's comment: do you want a solution in SQL or Javascript?

Comment: I prefer both, but more like the thought behind it, so I could apply to a multitude of languages.

Comment: @Eric: I need them to use programmatically. Basically, a free number would be the next id to use for the record entry.

Comment: The queries below are your friends, just pick the first value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will give you what you need:

```
SELECT seq_num
  FROM (SELECT (lvl + &&v_from - 1) seq_num
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM (    SELECT LEVEL lvl
                              FROM DUAL
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (&&v_to - &&v_from) + 1)))
 WHERE seq_num NOT IN (SELECT my_identifier FROM my_table);
```

Replace &&v_to and &&v_from with your boundary numbers.

Reference: http://oraqa.com/2006/01/20/how-to-generate-sequence-numbers-between-two-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not really related to that, isn't it?
I did something similiar years before.

I had a table with all numbers in a range and joined these two tables and selected those numbers which could not be joined. A negative select.

Something like

```
 select nr bulk collect into nrs1 from tbl1 where nr not in
                (select nr from tbl2);
```